# Ключевое слово void, его особенности и return

Tags: java

Пример:

```
public class Person {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.run(12,2);
    }
    public void run(int a, int b){
        System.out.println(a+b);
    }
}
```

Выводится в консоль: 14

Пример 2:

```
public class Person {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person();
        System.out.println(person.run(12, 2));
    }

    public int run(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Выводится в консоль: 14

Не могу понять зачем нам `void`, если мы можем написать `public **int** run(...)`

Пытаюсь разобраться с void и return.

Comment: В первом примере функция `run` не возвращает __ничего__.

Comment: Вы видите одно и то же, а под капотом происходит разное. Можно вообще просто написать в методе ``main`` одну строчку ``System.out.println("14");`` и спрашивать, зачем нам вообще нужны какие-то функции, методы и классы, когда я просто могу вывести "14" одной строчкой кода.

Comment: Вы месяц назад уже задавали такой вопрос и даже отметили один из ответов. Зачем опять задавать такой же вопрос?

Comment: @Эникейщик я понял как это работает, но не пойму что использовать и как? Потому что выше 2 примера работают одинаково.

Comment: @Эникейщик то есть 1 пример говорит: зачем нам return если можно сделать так (как в 1 примере)

Comment: Они работают **по-разному**! Одинаковй результат не означает "работают одинаково".

Comment: Иван, хорошо, что вы изучаете всё так тщательно. Ещё больше меня радует, что некоторые моменты вам бывают понятны сразу))

Comment: @ИгорьГор спасибо! Либо знаешь хорошо либо не знаешь :)

Comment: @ИгорьГор Да вопросов куча, но скоро думаю меня тут забанят за такое количество вопросов :D хоть и с положительными голосами

Answer (score 3):

Весь смысл функции с типом `void` - это действия без отчета. Если функция не `void` , то она по возвращает какой-то результат и заканчивает работу.
В первом примете, если у вас, к примеру, нет доступа к консоли, вы никогда не узнаете о том, что функция выполнена.
Во втором случаи, функция отсылает "отчет" о том, что она сделала, и вы видите результат. 
И так, `void` используем для функций, которые работают независимо и мы не ждем от них "отчета".

Ключевое слово `return` прекращает выполнение функции. Можно использовать и в циклах (`break`), функциях.

Например,

```
public void count(int stop) {
     for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
           System.out.println(i);
           if (i == stop) { return; }
     }
}
```

В данном случаи мы в функцию передаем число, после которого следует прекратить вывод чисел.

Comment: Я вижу результат в 1 и во 2 примере одинаковый

Comment: Почему все пишут "функция" если это метод?

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван, потому что любой метод = это функция, но не любая функция это метод.

Answer (score 2):

`void` означает что функция не возвращает результат, все остальные варианты (например `int`) будут обозначать тип возвращаемого значения и что функция обязана будет что-то вернуть.

Вот так компилироваться не будет, потому что нет `return`'а:

```
public int run(int a, int b) {
    int c = a + b;
    // return c;
}
```

---

`void` функции могут использовать `return`, но тот ничего не будет возвращать, например:

```
void log(String text) {
    // Если строка -- null, выходим из функции 
    if (text == null) {
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("text: " + text);
}

log("123");
log(null);
log("abc");
```

Comment: Почему функция? в Java же методы

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван, это равнозначные названия: функция и метод. Смысл может менять в зависимости от контекста, например метод -- это функция объекта. А лямбда -- безымянная (анонимная) функция. При этом методы и лямбды являются функциями